# How to fix this "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified" (Windows)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server

I want to connect with tomcat server with eclips IDE. I have already install tomcat 8.5 and 9.0 versions. 
Both versions shows this error.

[image]

So please help me how can I configure my eclipse with tomcat any versions

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an installed copy of Tomcat. Instead, download the Core zip/tar file and unpack it somewhere under your user's home directory. It has the most predictable layout for needed files and avoid any write permission issues you might have with an installed copy.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F